# Adding Presto as a data source for Grafana

Tags: hadoop, visualization, grafana, presto

I want to use Grafana as my visualization tool for creating dashboards. On the other hand, we are using Presto extensively in our Hadoop ecosystem. I am wondering if there is a way to visualize Presto query results with Grafana.
So far I have found this that doesn't have any good documentation.

https://github.com/viirya/grafana-presto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually currently there is no possible way to user Presto as Grafana data source. I offer you that use [Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset),[Redash](https://redash.io/) or [Metabase](http://metabase.com/) as a visualization tool for your company! they are designed for this reason

Comment: We did move to Superset!